# Non WWW redirect to WWW and non SSL to SSL - htaccess

Tags: htaccess, apache, 301-redirect

I'm trying to redirect my Wordpress site from non www to WWW and non SSL to SSL permamently.

Here's the code I'm using:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301] 

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

I wonder if the code is right or it can be done a better way? I mean, it seems to work but PageSpeed says that I should avoid that many redirections.

EDIT: So it should look like that:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

?

EDIT2:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^static.example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://static.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have is perfectly OK and would need to be implemented that way (by redirecting to HTTPS on the same host) if you intend to implement [HSTS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security).

However, to eliminate a double redirect when requesting `http://example.com`, you should reverse those two rules. Otherwise, you'll get the following double redirect:

- `http://example.com` to `https://example.com` to`https://www.example.com`

For example:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

No need to repeat the `RewriteEngine` directive.

No need to capture a backreference (ie. `(.*)`) when it's not being used in the *substitution*. No need for the anchors `^` and `$` since regex is greedy by default.

The other "style" inconsistency between the above rules, is that you are using a captured backreference (`$1`) in the first `RewriteRule` and the `REQUEST_URI` server variable in the second. It makes no difference in how it works as it does the same thing in two different ways. But they are two different "styles" (as if written by two different people).

---

**EDIT2:**

> I also have a subdomain - `static.example.com` (non www). I would like to add SSL here and redirect WWW to non WWW (now users can access the site through www as well, ending up with URL like `www.static.example.com`). I tried something like in EDIT2 (I just edited my post). Can you tell me what's wrong with that code?
>
> ```
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^static.example\.com [NC]
> RewriteRule (.*) https://static.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
>
> RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
> RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
> ```

Your first rule here is redirecting `static.example.com` to `static.example.com` (ie. no change) - so this will naturally result in a never ending redirect loop (the browser will eventually break with an error).

If you are wanting to redirect *from* `www.static.example.com` then you should be checking for this in the `RewriteCond` directive. For example:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.static\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://static.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

I don't know whether you are or not, but there is no need to repeat the HTTP to HTTPS redirect - providing you put the directives in the correct order.

**So, in summary, with both redirects together:**

```
RewriteEngine On

# Main domain non-www to www redirect
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]

# Subdomain www to non-www redirect
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.static\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://static.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]

# HTTP to HTTPS redirect
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Thank you, but what do you mean exactly by "reverse those two rules"? How should the code look like?

Comment: You have two code blocks in your example. Put the second one first. (Sorry, I'm on mobile at the mo - editing is awkward.)

Comment: So it should look like that (please check edited post)?

Comment: Yes, that's right. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you! One more question: I also have a subdomain - static.example.com (non www). I would like to add SSL here and redirect WWW to non WWW (now users can access the site through www as well, ending up with URL like www.static.example.com). I tried something like in EDIT2 (I just edited my post). Can you tell me what's wrong with that code?

Comment: In EDIT2 you are redirecting from `static.example.com` not `www.static....`, which will result in a redirect loop. I've updated my answer.